# Getting all documents of a database in CouchDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, cradle

The `get()` method of the Cradle library requires me to provide an `_id`. CouchDB provides an `_all_docs` view, but there's nothing in the Cradle documentation about this.

How can I get all documents from a single CouchDB database with Cradle?

Answer (score 7):

Cradle provides an [`all()`](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle#database-level) method which acts on a database. It queries the `_all_docs` view and returns the results.

It should look something like this.

```
var cradle = require('cradle'),
    db = new(cradle.Connection)().database('your-db');

db.all(function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error: %s', err)
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }
});
```